# Parsing non-standard files for text using PowerShell and Select-String

Tags: file, powershell, parsing, powershell-2.0

Microsoft Remote Desktop saved sessions have values in them when you open them with a text editor (to test yourself, open Remote Desktop Connection, click Options, and then click Save As. Open the resulting .rdp file in a text editor).

However, using the standard `Select-String` command here (which works when exactly the same syntax on other file formats):

```
$MyOObject."Prompt" = (Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern "promptcredentialonce: (.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

... produces the following error:

> Cannot index a null array

Is there a different command to use to parse this kind of file, or any non standard text file, in PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: @wOxxOm I have updated the post with the code I am using

Comment: `Matches` is an array so in PS2 you need `Matches[0]` or foreach/where/select-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect. The syntax of the options in .rdp files is

```
name:type:value
```

In your case:

```
promptcredentialonce:i:0
```

However, you're trying to match something with a space after the option name (which doesn't exist):

```
promptcredentialonce: (.*)
```

Without a match the `.Matches` property is empty and `.Group[1]` attempts an indexed access on a null value.

If you want the value including the type, remove the space:

```
promptcredentialonce:(.*)
```

If you want just the value, change the pattern to something like this:

```
promptcredentialonce:\w+:(.*)
```